# Input set default values on its own

Tags: html, ajax

I have made a form in HTML everything must work very well but there is sth very strange about it. when I check the form on a browser I see my inputs have default values. the values I haven't give them.

"creator" for text input and ***** for password input. I don't know why it's happening I just noticed it happens when I set my password type input equal to 'password' if I change it to text everything will be fine.

this is my form

```
 <form class="form-group">

            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='user_email' placeholder="username..." Required /><br>
            <input type='password' class='form-control' id='user_PassEnter' placeholder="password..." Required /><br>

           </form>
```

I also should mention the values change when I use other browsers. for example on Chrome the text input value became ajax.

Comment: `Required` capital letters are not allowed in attribute names. The behaviour you observed probably is caused by an auto-fill feature of your browser. Re-check with a browser that has never before seen the form.

Comment: Try incognito and see if this is still happening. Also set `autoComplete="off"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by either:

1. Disabling autocomplete using `<form class = "form-group" autocomplete="off">`

2.Remove data from your auto-fill in the settings of your browser.

Each browser has their own way of doing it, which you can find by a simple internet search.

Comment: didn't work! I also used autocomplete="false" but didn't make any change

Comment: @rezahooshyarr have you tried browsing in incognito/private?